# Iphone dev - ViewDidUnload

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using ARC

In some tutorials I'm watching, he once made a UILabel and then in the method ViewDidUnload he wrote: self.theLabelVariable = nil;
I have not seen him write anything in ViewDidUnload again since then.. yet.

I'm a bit confused to what code is supposed to go in that method.

1.
What and when should I write in it?
It's commented:
"Release any retained subviews of the main view. E.g. self.myOutlet = nil;"
Not really sure what that's upposed to mean though

2.
It also has a "[super ViewDidUnload]" What does that do?

3.
Someone said "etting it to nil when you don't intend to use it again is a good idea".
But in the tutorial where someone wrote "self.TheLabelVariable = nil", when I hit the home button and then brought the app up again, everything worked fine.
Or is it not cViewDidUnload when you hit the home button?
I suppose the third question is: When is it called?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this with all of your `IBOutlets`. You should set them all to `nil`. And `[super viewDidUnload];` is unloading the superview! Its sort of like `[super viewDidLoad];`

Answer (score 0):

1 - You should use viewDidUnload to release (set to nil if it's a property) any object that is not needed when the view is unloaded, like views, and that you'll recreate again on viewDidLoad. Example: You don't need a label when the view is unloaded (by pressing the home button), then you release it, and then you create it again when the view loads (app come up).

2 - [super something] calls the method on the super class. For example, if you have a class that is a descendant of UIViewController calling [super viewDidUnload] will execute the Apple's UIViewController viewDidUnload code (which might be empty... or not).

3 - See the example on 1. But the thing is: when you don't need an object anymore set it to nil so it can be released and you're not wasting memory.

Let me know if I missed something or if there's something you didn't understand.

**EDIT**

For views that are initialized from a XIB file (interface builder), called IBOutlets, you don't need to do self.label=nil; because UIViewController does it for you. Just like it initialized it for you, it will release it too.

Comment: Great answer, just one more question or two...  1. Does that mean that if i put self.label = nil; in ViewDidUnload, do I have to do self.label = something in ViewDidLoad? But in the code where he put self.label = nil;, he didn't write anything in ViewDidLoad, but the label still Said 'blue' after pressning the home button and then bringing it up again. And the app still worked (press Button -> change text of label)

Comment: I use a storyboard if that makes any difference. So if I go to my storyboard, drag in a

Comment: drag in a label or UITextField, do property on it in viewcontroller.h, synthesize it in viewcontroller.h I dont need to do self.variable = nil? 1. When is it initialized 'from XIB'?  Your first answer made me feel like every Button, label etc should be set to nil in ViewDidUnload, your last answer (the edit) make it sound like nothing should be set to nil because it does that automatically

Comment: The basic feeling is, if a class does not initialize (alloc) a variable it does not release it, search for the ownership rule.

Comment: And it's not everything, you can make an entire app without using IB, and in that case you have to manage your objects yourself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8546/discussion-between-user1021085-and-fbernardo)

Comment: OK, I'll have the chat page open, so just drop by when you can.